# Use set amount of ram and paging file

Tags: java

Is it possible to set max ram for java to say 20Gb and then any excess usage gets put in paging file.

At the moment I can specify for example 500gb max and it completely fills ram and starts writing to paging file but due to it completely using all ram first it causes the system to lock up.

I think that this is down to the OS implementation but I am not sure if there's some argument which may allow this

Answer (score 0):

Virtual memory is handled transparently by the OS. Java doesn't know or care whether the memory given to it is actual RAM or partially in a swap file, and it won't or can't make any decisions based on it either.